# Elasticsearch server conflict

Tags: ruby, rubygems, elasticsearch, nagios

I'm trying to make a check_elasticsearch_cluser Nagios plugin to work. But, the plugin file has a

```
require 'elasticsearch'
```

line (for defining a client). That's from the elasticsearch gem. I check the service with

```
./check_elasticsearch_cluser.rb --ip MY_IP --port 9200
```

I installed the elasticsearch server.

The problem is that, without the gem, the ruby file can't locate the gem (it fails on the *require* line). But with the gem, IP:9200 is not available! So it says:

```
Connection refused - connect(2) for "107.170.106.xxx" port 9200 (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
```

Comment: Ve you tried with port 9300??